# Generated DocSet causes Xcode 4.6 crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, doxygen

I currently use Xcode 4.6.
I wrote a script in order to generate HTML and DocSet documentation (XCode Run Script).
My script work like a charm. I'm able to access HTML documentation and also
(re)load it within Xcode.

However accessing of some of my tabs like "Main Page" or "Related Pages" causes
Xcode crash.

If you've any ideas about a temporary solutions (maybe in doxygen conf file ?), I'm interested !

Best regards !

Pebie

PS : I've bug report with file attachement here : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is not a doxygen bug but Apple one.
See answers here from doxygen team : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697706

Best regards !